How to mock a enum or the method of enum from a different rs-file for unit test in Rust?
I have a enum DBUtl defined in file src/db_utl.rs. It is to provide path/directory of folders for Case1 and Case2. It implements a method path. So other code can get the path of, e.g. Case1 by DBUtl::Case1.path().
// file: src/db_utl.rs

use std::{env, path::PathBuf};

pub enum DBUtl {
    Case1,
    Case2,
}

impl DBUtl {
    pub fn path(&self) -> PathBuf {
        let cwd = env::current_dir().unwrap();
        match self {
            DBUtl::Case1 => cwd.join("folder_1"),
            DBUtl::Case2 => cwd.join("folder_2"),
        }
    }
}

I have another file src/learn.rs which uses DBUtl. Here my aim is to mock/fake the returned path of DBUtl::Case1.path() in the unit test below, for the function get_learn_file().
// file: src/learn.rs (Original, without unit test)

use crate::db_utl::DBUtl;

use mockall::predicate::*;
use mockall::*;

fn get_learn_file() {
    let file = DBUtl::Case1.path().join("my_learn.txt");
    println!("file: {:?}", file);
    // read and return the file content ... Not important for now.
}

I have tried myself with the mockall library, mockall = "0.13.0", but could not succeed.
// file: src/learn.rs (I tried to added unit test with the mockall library, not working yet)

use crate::db_utl::DBUtl;

use mockall::predicate::*;
use mockall::*;

fn get_learn_file() {
    let file = DBUtl::Case1.path().join("my_learn.txt");
    println!("file: {:?}", file);
    // read and return the file content ... Not important for now.
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use std::path::PathBuf;

    use super::*;

    // Mock the DBUtl enum. This is my try. Not sure if it is correct or not.
    mock! {
        pub DBUtl {
            pub fn path(&self) -> PathBuf;
        }

        impl Clone for DBUtl {
            fn clone(&self) -> Self;
        }
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_get_file() {
        let mut mock_db_utl = MockDBUtl::new();
        mock_db_utl
            .expect_path()
            .returning(|| PathBuf::from("/Users/fake_folder"));

        // How to let get_learn_file() use the MockDBUtl instead of the real one?
        get_learn_file();
        // I will later assert the file content. Not important for now.
    }
}

Can you please show me how to write the unit test correctly? Please feel free to suggest other mock libraries that is better than mockall for this question. I am a beginner to Rust.
By the way:

I have tried to put folder: PathBuf as the input parameter of get_learn_file function like this get_learn_file(folder: PathBuf), then in my unit test I can provide the test path instead of the real path. This will work. However, I also want to learn how to mock, since there will be lots of situations I cannot change the function's signature but have to mock.

To try my code on your computer, you might want to add this to your src/lib.rs file, to expose them.
// file: src/lib.rs

pub mod db_utl;
pub mod learn;



Thanks in advance!

For mocking in Rust, you will need to have either a trait or a cfg. mockall requires the former.
